# How to pass mutiple values to ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbLQG.png)

When i click the button,am calling a function it will return some values.I need to get those values and send through AJAX using Jquery.

Give below the click button function.Inside this function am calling another function(here returning values i need to pass through ajax)

The problem is i cant able to send those values inside ajax.

Can anyone plz help me to do this?I dont know where am doing mistakes.

```
var dataSetsave = [];

   function saveschedule(startDate, endDate, periodInDays,cnt) {
          //dataSetsave = [];  
          var numWorkDays = 0;
          var currentDate = new Date(startDate);  

          while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
            currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
            // Skips friday
            if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
              numWorkDays++;
            }
            if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
              numWorkDays = 0;
              cnt++;
              let date = dateToYMD(currentDate);
              let pos = holidays.indexOf(date);
              if (pos != -1) {
                //console.log("replace",date,"with",instead[pos])
                date = instead[pos];
              }  
              let treatment = pad(cnt) + nth(cnt) + (cnt == 1 ? " Basic" : " Control") + " Treatment"
              dataSetsave.push([treatment, date])
            }
          }
return dataSetsave;
        }
```

How to pass dataSetsave.push([treatment, date]) to  ajax and pass to controller php?

Save to database like

```
Date
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03 so on.......
```

Whetever results coming from the function.Multiple rows i need to pass through AJAX.

Full code (button clicks)

```
$('#saveactivityarea').on('click', function(event) { //save new activity area       
    $('#newModalFormactivityarea').validate({
      rules: {
        act_contractbranch_name: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        act_contractbranch_name: {
          required: "Required"
        }
```

},

```
submitHandler: function(form) { 
    var act_contractbranch_name = $("#act_contractbranch_name").val();
var act_job_freq_contract = $("#act_job_freq_contract option:selected").val();
var act_city_activity = $("#act_city_activity option:selected").val();
var act_contractbranch_addr = $("#act_contractbranch_addr").val();
var act_contractbranch_contactname = $("#act_contractbranch_contactname").val();
var act_contractbranch_phone = $("#act_contractbranch_phone").val();
var act_contractbranch_emailid = $("#act_contractbranch_emailid").val();
var act_contractbranch_FAX = $("#act_contractbranch_FAX").val();
var fjd_date = $('#act_contractbranch_firstjobdt').val(); //24-06-2019
var act_contractbranch_firstjobdt = fjd_date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
var act_contractbranch_firstjd = new Date(fjd_date.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
var contractID = $('#contractID').val();
var confirstjobdt = $('.Contractend_firstjobdt').val();
var contractend_firstjobdt = new Date(confirstjobdt.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
var act_job_freq_daysbtw = $("#act_job_freq_contract option:selected").attr('data-freqdays');
var branch_pestorclean = $("#branch_pestorclean option:selected").val();
var branch_treatmenttype = $('#branch_treatmenttype').val();
var returnedValues = saveschedule(act_contractbranch_firstjd,contractend_firstjobdt,act_job_freq_daysbtw,0);



        var contractID = $('#contractID').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'activity_submitted',
          data: {
            getcontractbranch_name: act_contractbranch_name,
            getcontractbranch_freq: act_job_freq_contract,
            getbranch_city: act_city_activity,
            getcontractbranch_addr: act_contractbranch_addr,
            getcontractbranch_contactname: act_contractbranch_contactname,
            getcontractbranch_phone: act_contractbranch_phone,
            getcontractbranch_emailid: act_contractbranch_emailid,
            getcontractbranch_FAX: act_contractbranch_FAX,
            getcontractbranch_firstjobdt: act_contractbranch_firstjobdt,
            getpest_or_clean: branch_pestorclean,
            get_typeof_treatment: branch_treatmenttype,
            getdataSetsave: returnedValues,
            //getjob_schedule_frequency: job_schedule_frequency,
            getcontract_id: contractID

          }, 
          success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);

          } //end success
        });
      }
    });
  }); //save activity area
```

PHPMODAL FUNCTION

```
$data_jobschedule = array(
            'jobschedule_id' => $jobschedule_id,
            'Activity_area_id' => $Activity_area_id,
            'Contract_id' => $this->input->post('getcontract_id'),
            'job_freq_id' => $this->input->post('getcontractbranch_freq'),
            'job_schedule_dates' => $this->input->post('getschedule'),
            //'job_schedule_frequency' => $this->input->post('getjob_schedule_frequency'),
            'created_at' =>$created_Dt
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) at the end of the `saveschedule` funtion.

> The return statement ends function execution **and specifies a value to be returned** to the function caller.

So at the end of the function, simply return the `dataSetsave` array:

```
return dataSetsave;
```

Then... The caller is the `submitHandler`. So just assign the retuned value of `saveschedule` to a variable. Like:

```
returnedValues = saveschedule(...);
```

Finally, use that in the Ajax `data` object:

```
data: {
  schedule: returnedValues,
  getcontractbranch_name: act_contractbranch_name,
  ...
```

Comment: i need to set two arrays .In the function it return two dataSetsave.push([treatment, date]). TREATMENT AND DATE..there are two columns in database table

Comment: showing insertion error INSERT INTO job_schedule (jobschedule_id, Activity_area_id, Contract_id, job_freq_id, job_schedule_dates, created_at) VALUES ('2119', '2118', '14', '1', Array, '2019-08-26 06:20:52')

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Array'.

Comment: job_schedule_dates adding Array and its showing  invalid column name Array

Comment: i try to console.log(dataSetsave) before the ajax; this result i will update screenshort above the code plz check it

Comment: Try to change the array into a CSV string... Use PHP [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)...

Comment: Didi u check my error schreeshot that i have attached above??

Comment: can u plz show me where i need to change?? to solve the problem??plz check my sreenshot.In that i passing  Date only still getting error

Comment: can u plz check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655134/how-to-split-array-and-save-to-database